# More on "Cylinder shading with pgf TiKZ"

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

In [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10707/1952) to [Cylinder shading with PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/cylinder-shading-with-pgf-tikz), Jake provides a code to draw a shaded cylinder with a not shaded top.

This code draws a cylinder node (from `shapes.geometric` library) and after that, with a second draw command, an ellipse is drawn over it.

I've tried to join both steps within a `mycylinder/.style` with an `append after command` option without any success. I still don't completely understand what `\pgfinterruptpath`, `\pgfextra` do, so may be my code is not correct. I imagine that covering ellipse must be drawn after shading the cylinder but I don't know how to do it. Could you explain what's wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,backgrounds,positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,
   >=stealth',
   mycylinder/.style={
draw,
  shape=cylinder,
  alias=cyl, % Will be used by the ellipse to reference the cylinder
  aspect=1.5,
  minimum height=3cm,
  minimum width=2cm,
  left color=blue!30,
  right color=blue!60,
  middle color=blue!10, % Has to be called after left color and middle color
  outer sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth, % to make sure the ellipse does not draw over the lines
  shape border rotate=90,
  append after command={%
    \pgfextra{%
       \pgfinterruptpath
%          \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}
          \fill [blue!10] let
             \p1 = ($(\tikzlastnode.before top)!0.5! (\tikzlastnode.after top)$),
             \p2 = (\tikzlastnode.top),
             \p3 = (\tikzlastnode.before top),
             \n1={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)},
             \n2={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},
             \n3={atan2((\y2-\y1),(\x2-\x1))}
          in 
             (\p1) ellipse [x radius=\n1, y radius = \n2, rotate=\n3];
%          \end{pgfonlayer}
       \endpgfinterruptpath%
    }
  }
 }
]

% Left cylinder. Wrong one.
% I would like to draw right cylinder with only one command.
\path node [mycylinder, label=below:Wrong] (disc) {};

% Right cylinder. Correct one but with two commands.
\path node [mycylinder, right=1cm of disc, label=below:Good] (disc2) {};
\fill [blue!10] let
  \p1 = ($(cyl.before top)!0.5!(cyl.after top)$),
  \p2 = (cyl.top),
  \p3 = (cyl.before top),
  \n1={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)},
  \n2={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},
  \n3={atan2((\y2-\y1),(\x2-\x1))}
 in 
  (\p1) ellipse [x radius=\n1, y radius = \n2, rotate=\n3];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TikZ already includes the possibility to insert a separate path in the current one: the `edge`.
(Unfortunately, you cannot use `pgfonlayer` here. But as the argument `append after command` will be executed after the node has been placed, this shouldn’t be an issue here.)

Since the CVS version swapped the arguments to the `atan2` function (`atan2(x, y)` to `atan2(y, x)`), I also included a small block in the preamble to sort this out and define the functions `atanXY` and `atanYX`.

I also chose to not change the `outer sep`s but instead to subtract `\pgflinewidth` directly from the radius. It is an annoyance that these values cannot be accessed after the node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\pgfmathparse{atan2(0,1)}
\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt % atan2(y, x)
  \tikzset{declare function={atanXY(\x,\y)=atan2(\y,\x);atanYX(\y,\x)=atan2(\y,\x);}}
\else                       % atan2(x, y)
  \tikzset{declare function={atanXY(\x,\y)=atan2(\x,\y);atanYX(\y,\x)=atan2(\x,\y);}}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,
   mycylinder/.style={draw, shape=cylinder, aspect=1.5, minimum height=+3cm,
    minimum width=+2cm, left color=blue!30, right color=blue!60, middle color=blue!10,
    shape border rotate=90, append after command={%
      let \p{cyl@center} = ($(\tikzlastnode.before top)!0.5! (\tikzlastnode.after top)$),
          \p{cyl@x}      = ($(\tikzlastnode.before top)-(\p{cyl@center})$),
          \p{cyl@y}      = ($(\tikzlastnode.top)       -(\p{cyl@center})$)
      in (\p{cyl@center}) edge[draw=none, fill=blue!10, to path={
        ellipse [x radius=veclen(\p{cyl@x})-1\pgflinewidth,
                 y radius=veclen(\p{cyl@y})-1\pgflinewidth,
                 rotate=atanXY(\p{cyl@x})]}] () }}]
\node[mycylinder, label=below:Better?] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Another idea.

The `cylinder` shape already has the option to fill the two parts differently with the options

- `cylinder body fill=<color>`,
- `cylinder end fill=<color>` and the switch
- `cylinder uses custom fill`.

Unfortunately, the shading in

```
cylinder end fill=blue!10,  cylinder uses custom fill,
preaction={draw=red, left color=blue!30, right color=blue!60, middle color=blue!10}
```

will be drawn on top of the `cylinder end fill` (which is done in a `behindbackgroundpath`) even though the shading itself is in a `preaction`.

It may be possible to solve this with a custom shape.

The keys `Cylinder end shade` and `Cylinder body shade` actually are implemented by setting their content with `\tikzset` and using `\tikz@finish` (similar how the `backgroundpath` and the `foregroundpath` are applied).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pgfset{
  Cylinder end fill/.initial=,
  Cylinder body fill/.initial=,
  Cylinder end shade/.initial=,
  Cylinder body shade/.initial=}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{Cylinder}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=cylinder]%
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=cylinder]%
  \inheritanchorborder[from=cylinder]%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{center}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{shape center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{mid}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{mid west}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{base east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{north}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{north east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{south east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{before top}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{top}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{after top}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{before bottom}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{bottom}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{after bottom}%
  \behindbackgroundpath{%
    \ifpgfcylinderusescustomfill%
      \getcylinderpoints%
      \pgf@x\xradius\relax%
      \advance\pgf@x-\outersep\relax%
      \edef\xradius{\the\pgf@x}%
      \pgf@y\yradius\relax%
      \advance\pgf@y-\outersep\relax%
      \edef\yradius{\the\pgf@y}%
      {%
        \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
        \pgftransformrotate{\rotate}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\afterbottom}%
        \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\beforetop\pgf@y-\pgf@y}%
        \pgfpatharc{270}{90}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        \pgfpathclose%
        \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder body fill}}%
        \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
          \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder body shade}}%
          \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfusepath{discard}%
          \else % make shading:
            \begingroup
            \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\pgf@temp}
            \tikz@finish
          \fi
        \else
          \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@temp}%
          \pgfusepath{fill}%
        \fi
        %
        \pgfpathmoveto{\beforetop}%
        \pgfpatharc{90}{-270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        \pgfpathclose
        \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder end fill}}%
        \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
          \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder end shade}}%
          \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfusepath{discard}%
          \else % make shading: 
            \begingroup
            \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\pgf@temp}
            \tikz@finish
          \fi
        \else
          \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@temp}%
          \pgfusepath{fill}%
        \fi
      }%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small, opacity=1,
   mycylinder/.style={shape=Cylinder, aspect=1.5, minimum height=+3cm, draw,
     cylinder uses custom fill, Cylinder end fill=blue!10,
     Cylinder body shade={left color=blue!30, right color=blue!60, middle color=blue!10},
     minimum width=+2cm,  shape border rotate=90,
  }]
\node[mycylinder, label=below:Betterer?] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]