# Drawing cylinder 3d (inside each other)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to graph the same figure using latex,

Any idea where to start?

[image]

Update, I tried the following code .. it is not near what I want

```
   \documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [fill=white, fill opacity=.05,line width=0.0mm]
  (180:5mm) coordinate (a)
  -- ++(0,3mm) coordinate (b)
  arc (180:360:5mm and 1.75mm) coordinate (d)
  -- (a -| d) coordinate (c) ;
 \draw [fill=white, fill opacity=.05,line width=0.0mm]
  (0,0) coordinate (t) circle (5mm and 1.75mm);
  \draw [line width=0.0mm] (d) arc (0:180:5mm and 1.75mm);
  
  
  
  
    \draw [fill=white, fill opacity=.05,line width=0.0mm]
  (-.5mm,0.25) coordinate (a2)
  -- ++(0,4mm) coordinate (b2)
  arc (180:360:.5mm and 0.15mm) coordinate (d2)
  -- (a2 -| d2) coordinate (c2) arc (0:180:.5mm and 0.15mm);
   \draw [fill=white, fill opacity=.5,line width=0.0mm]
  (0,0.25) coordinate (t) circle (.5mm and 0.15mm);
  \draw [dashed,line width=0.0mm] (d2) arc (0:180:.5mm and 0.15mm);
  

  \draw [line width=0.0mm]
  (0,0) coordinate (T) circle (7.5mm and 2.625mm);
  \draw [fill=myblue, fill opacity=.05,line width=0.0mm]
  (180:7.5mm) coordinate (A)
  -- ++(0,-5.5mm) coordinate (B) node [midway, right, inner sep=1pt] {}
  arc (180:360:7.5mm and 2.625mm) coordinate (D)
  -- (A -| D) coordinate (C) arc (0:180:7.5mm and 2.625mm);
    \draw [line width=0.0mm] (D) arc (0:180:7.5mm and 2.625mm);

  -- (T) node [midway, right, anchor=west, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {} node [anchor=center, circle, draw, solid, inner sep=.5pt, fill=white] {} edge [solid, -Latex] node [right, pos=1] {} ++(0,5mm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any adjustments to make it look better is appreciated.

Comment: This is a quite plain drawing that you may be able to achieve layer by layer, with some `opacity` tunings. Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 8):

Probably the best solution is to use the `shapes.geometric` library, and do something like what is indicated here: [More on "Cylinder shading with pgf TiKZ"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122590/more-on-cylinder-shading-with-pgf-tikz).

However, recycling a previous drawing of mine involving cylinders, I can offer you an alternative, something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage    {ifthen}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\cylinder}[5] % center, radius (y-axis), height (to the right), color, opacity
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\r {0.5*#2}              % radius (x-axis)
  \coordinate (C1)  at #1;                 % center, left ellipse
  \coordinate (N1)  at ($(C1)+(0,#2)$);    % north, left ellipse  
  \coordinate (NW1) at ($(C1)+(-\r,#2)$);  % north west, left ellipse
  \coordinate (W1)  at ($(C1)-(\r,0)$);    % west, left ellipse  
  \coordinate (S1)  at ($(C1)-(0,#2)$);    % south, left ellipse 
  \coordinate (P1)  at ($(W1)!0.1!(NW1)$); % point for shading
  \coordinate (Q1)  at ($(W1)!0.2!(NW1)$); % another point for shading
  \coordinate (C2)  at ($(C1)+(#3,0)$);    % center, right ellipse
  \coordinate (N2)  at ($(N1)+(#3,0)$);    % ...
  \coordinate (S2)  at ($(S1)+(#3,0)$);
  \coordinate (P2)  at ($(P1)+(#3,0)$);
  \ifthenelse
    {\equal{#3}{0}} % if height is 0
    {} % then do nothing
    {  % else...
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (N1) arc (90:270:\r cm and #2 cm) -- (S2) -- (S2) arc (270:90:\r cm and #2 cm) -- cycle;
        \shade[top color=white, bottom color=#4!65,fill opacity=#5] (S2) rectangle (P1);
        \shade[top color=#4!55, bottom color=white,fill opacity=#5] (N2) rectangle (Q1);
        \fill[white, opacity=#5] (P2) rectangle (Q1);
      \end{scope}
      \draw[#4] (N2) -- (N1) arc (90:270:\r cm and #2 cm) -- (S2);
    }
  \draw[#4,fill=#4!12.5,opacity=#5] (C2) ellipse (\r cm and #2 cm);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line cap=round,line join=round]
  \cylinder{(0,0)}{0.75}{2}{blue} {1};
  \cylinder{(0,0)}{1}   {2}{black}{0.75};
  \cylinder{(2,0)}{0.75}{1}{blue} {1};
  \cylinder{(3,0)}{0.1} {0}{red}  {1};
  \fill(3,0) circle (0.25pt);
  \draw[very thin,dashed] (2,1) -- (3.5,1);
  \draw[very thin,dashed] (3,0.75) -- (4,0.75);
  \draw[very thin,dashed] (3,0.1) -- (3.6,0.1);
  \draw[very thin,dashed] (3,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw[-latex] (3.5,1) node [above right] {Refractive index} -- (6,1);
  \draw[red!80!black] (3.7,1) |- (3.6,0.75) |- (4,0.1) -- (4,0);
  \node at (4,0.875) [right] {Coating};
  \node at (4,0.425) [right] {Cladding};
  \node at (4,0.05)  [right] {Core}; 
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

This is the drawing:
[image]

Comment: Very good and my compliments.

Comment: Clever solution, and very understandable. Congrats.